# Can you undelete this answer I fixed the request you made

Tags: discussion

[How to use NAT iptables rules for hostapd](https://superuser.com/questions/616642/how-to-use-nat-iptables-rules-for-hostapd/1305421#1305421)

Sorry for taking so long, busy moving cross country.

Comment: @Ramhound you may want to click the link. He refers to an answer he posted that was deleted by DavidPostill

Comment: Answer undeleted.

Answer (score 9):

In future, flagging is a good way of getting this done - use a custom flag like "Hi - I've fixed up the issues raised - could I have this undeleted please", and a moderator will review it shortly. You can also post on meta, but this is a simple request that doesn't need much feedback so flagging is very much preferred.

It appears that one of my fellow moderators has reviewed your request and the post has been undeleted.